# USB pen drive not getting assigned anything in /dev/

Tags: linux, usb, filesystems, mount, dev

`dmesg | tail -f`:

```
[17597.228060] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
[17597.330548] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0300
[17597.330580] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[17597.330598] usb 1-1.3: Product: STORE N GO
[17597.330610] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Verbatim
[17597.330622] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: AA00000000002963
[17597.348020] scsi3 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
[17598.740790] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[17598.745420] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 63505152 512-byte logical blocks: (32.5 GB/30.2 GiB)
[17598.746251] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[17598.746282] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[17598.747136] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[17598.747164] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[17598.753856] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[17598.753888] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[17598.755286]  sda:
[17598.759699] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[17598.759730] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[17598.759751] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Tried to `sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /media/usb0/` anyway but unsurprisingly sda1 does not exist. The drive was formatted fat32 with gparted, then mounted on a windows box to collect a bunch of files and now I'm trying unsuccessfully to get debian to mount it, with the above dmesg output.

Anyone know what's going wrong?

edit: fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3965 MB, 3965190144 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 121008 cylinders, total 7744512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000dbfc6

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          122880     7744511     3810816   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 32.5 GB, 32514637824 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 31008 cylinders, total 63505152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6f20736b

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   ?   778135908  1919645538   570754815+  72  Unknown
/dev/sda2   ?   168689522  2104717761   968014120   65  Novell Netware 386
/dev/sda3   ?  1869881465  3805909656   968014096   79  Unknown
/dev/sda4   ?  2885681152  2885736650       27749+   d  Unknown

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: include `fdisk -l` output as well.

Comment: fdisk output included.

Comment: Have you tried "sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda /media/usb0/" ?  (IE is it possible that you have created a filesystem on the raw device rather then a partition table ?)

Comment: Did you try /dev/mmcblk0p1 and /dev/mmcblk0p2 ?

Comment: No, that's what my os is mounted on.
@davidgo got 'mount: /dev/sda: can't read superblock' response.